# Did Ivan Marchenko actually exist?

Tags: world-war-two, poland, holocaust, ukraine

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_the_Terrible_%28Treblinka_guard%29) (and other sources I saw) so very little is known about Ivan Marchenko that his name is not even mentioned in official documents around that time; even his date of birth is unsure.

What evidence is there that he was a real person?

Comment: Is there a reason the wikipedia article's evidence is inadequate?

Comment: @SamuelRussell it's not about the article, but the lack of informations about the person himself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about question begging denialism.

Comment: @SamuelRussell where to post it then?